# How to count the number of orders placed before each date by customer

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have two data sets, a smaller one:

```
OrderDate id no_of_orders_before_row_date 
01-Jul-17 1 0 
02-Jul-17 1 1 
02-Jul-17 2 0 
03-Jul-17 3 0 
01-Jul-17 4 0 
03-Jul-17 4 1 
05-Jul-17 5 0 
07-Jul-17 6 0 
09-Jul-17 2 1 
11-Jul-17 1 2 
13-Jul-17 4 2 
15-Jul-17 3 1
```

and a larger one which is available for download at

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1buF74VKwOj1-f_4hDPnP17vWqoUupMRnNz301laCLJM/edit#gid=0

[image]

Note that the larger data set is unsorted and includes multiple orders on the same day.

I am looking for the number of orders before the row date.

Excel formulae used was `=COUNTIFS($L:$L,L5,$K:$K,"<"&K5)`

where column `L` is `OrderDate` and column `K` is `id`.

How to do this in R?

Comment: Thanks a lot for reframing my question. I will keep it in mind for the next query.

Answer (score 1):

The OP has requested to count the orders placed by each `id` before the actual row date.

In case there is only order per day and id, this is equivalent to order the data.frame by `OrderDate` and to consecutively number all rows belonging to a particular `id` starting with 0. Unfortunately, this is only true for the small sample data set provided in the question but not for the larger data set which can be downloaded from the given link.

The larger data set contains ties, i.e., there are several cases where one customer has placed multiple orders on the same day. Here, the simple method will fail because it counts the rows even on the same day. This can be fixed using `rank()`.

#### Simple solution works with small data set

```
library(data.table)
# coerce to data.table
setDT(DT1)[
  # convert character date to class Date to ensure correct sort order
  , OrderDate := lubridate::dmy(OrderDate)][
    # order by date, create new column with the row numbers for each id
    order(OrderDate), previous_orders := (1:.N) - 1L, by = id][]
```

> ```
>      OrderDate id no_of_orders_before_row_date previous_orders
>  1: 2017-07-01  1                            0               0
>  2: 2017-07-02  1                            1               1
>  3: 2017-07-02  2                            0               0
>  4: 2017-07-03  3                            0               0
>  5: 2017-07-01  4                            0               0
>  6: 2017-07-03  4                            1               1
>  7: 2017-07-05  5                            0               0
>  8: 2017-07-07  6                            0               0
>  9: 2017-07-09  2                            1               1
> 10: 2017-07-11  1                            2               2
> 11: 2017-07-13  4                            2               2
> 12: 2017-07-15  3                            1               1
> ```

#### Simple solution fails with larger data set

Note that code below has been amended for the different column names and the result is sorted for printing to better show the failure.

```
setDT(DT2)[, Order.Date := lubridate::dmy(Order.Date)][
  order(Order.Date), previous_orders := (1:.N) - 1L, by = Phone.Number][
    order(Phone.Number, Order.Date)]
```

> ```
>     Order.Date Phone.Number Count previous_orders
>  1: 2017-07-09   7353478602     0               0
>  2: 2017-07-10   7353478602     1               1
>  3: 2017-07-11   7353478602     2               2
>  4: 2017-07-09   8123246689     0               0
>  5: 2017-07-10   8123246689     1               1
>  6: 2017-07-10   8123246689     1               2
>  7: 2017-07-11   8123246689     3               3
>  8: 2017-07-11   8123246689     3               4
>  9: 2017-07-12   8123246689     5               5
> 10: 2017-07-08   8867413567     0               0
> 11: 2017-07-09   9036580445     0               0
> 12: 2017-07-11   9164539082     0               0
> 13: 2017-07-09   9538991240     0               0
> 14: 2017-07-08   9675623760     0               0
> 15: 2017-07-12   9845798557     0               0
> 16: 2017-07-12   9886668467     0               0
> 17: 2017-07-10   9886728132     0               0
> 18: 2017-07-12   9902789900     0               0
> ```

Note the differences in rows 6 and 8. In both cases, the purchases on the same day were included in the count.

#### Using `rank()` to handle multiple purchases on the same day

The modified code below returns the correct result:

```
setDT(DT2)[, Order.Date := lubridate::dmy(Order.Date)][
  order(Order.Date), 
  previous_orders := frank(Order.Date, ties.method = "min") - 1L, 
  by = Phone.Number][
    order(Phone.Number, Order.Date)]
```

> ```
>     Order.Date Phone.Number Count previous_orders
>  1: 2017-07-09   7353478602     0               0
>  2: 2017-07-10   7353478602     1               1
>  3: 2017-07-11   7353478602     2               2
>  4: 2017-07-09   8123246689     0               0
>  5: 2017-07-10   8123246689     1               1
>  6: 2017-07-10   8123246689     1               1
>  7: 2017-07-11   8123246689     3               3
>  8: 2017-07-11   8123246689     3               3
>  9: 2017-07-12   8123246689     5               5
> 10: 2017-07-08   8867413567     0               0
> 11: 2017-07-09   9036580445     0               0
> 12: 2017-07-11   9164539082     0               0
> 13: 2017-07-09   9538991240     0               0
> 14: 2017-07-08   9675623760     0               0
> 15: 2017-07-12   9845798557     0               0
> 16: 2017-07-12   9886668467     0               0
> 17: 2017-07-10   9886728132     0               0
> 18: 2017-07-12   9902789900     0               0
> ```

In case the date column already has the correct class `Date`, the call to `lubridate::dmy()` will create NAs and must be omitted, e.g.,

```
setDT(rawdata)[order(orderdate), previous_orders := (1:.N) - 1L, by = phone][order(phone, orderdate)]
```

#### Data

Small data set as provided in the question:

```
DT1 <- structure(list(OrderDate = c("01-Jul-17", "02-Jul-17", "02-Jul-17", 
"03-Jul-17", "01-Jul-17", "03-Jul-17", "05-Jul-17", "07-Jul-17", 
"09-Jul-17", "11-Jul-17", "13-Jul-17", "15-Jul-17"), id = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L), no_of_orders_before_row_date = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("OrderDate", 
"id", "no_of_orders_before_row_date"), row.names = c(NA, -12L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Larger data set downloaded from the given link as csv file:

```
library(data.table)
DT2 <- fread("R doubts - Sheet1.csv", drop = 4L, skip = 1L, check.names = TRUE,
             colClasses = c("Phone Number" = "character"))
```

or

```
DT2 <- structure(list(Order.Date = c("8/7/2017", "9/7/2017", "10/7/2017", 
"11/7/2017", "12/7/2017", "9/7/2017", "10/7/2017", "11/7/2017", 
"12/7/2017", "9/7/2017", "10/7/2017", "11/7/2017", "12/7/2017", 
"9/7/2017", "10/7/2017", "11/7/2017", "12/7/2017", "8/7/2017"
), Phone.Number = c("9675623760", "9036580445", "7353478602", 
"7353478602", "9845798557", "7353478602", "8123246689", "9164539082", 
"9902789900", "9538991240", "9886728132", "8123246689", "8123246689", 
"8123246689", "8123246689", "8123246689", "9886668467", "8867413567"
), Count = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
5L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Order.Date", "Phone.Number", 
"Count"), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi Uwe, thanks a lot for taking out time to make me understand this. Request you to please explain what is happening in each of the code. I have migrated from excel to R and it looks very difficult to understand. Just want to understand what is happening in each of these codes and how do they operate. Thanks again for helping me out here..

Comment: Note - the code has been amended to fit the column name

When I use this code - setDT(rawdata)[, orderdate := lubridate::dmy(orderdate)][
  order(orderdate), previous_orders := (1:.N) - 1L, by = phone][
    order(phone, orderdate)]

and export it in CSV, it shows NA in order date. is it a correct output?

Comment: In `rawdata`, what type/class is `orderdate`?. Please check `str(rawdata)`.

Comment: str(rawdata)
'data.frame': 139418 obs. of  15 variables:

Comment: orderdate     : Date, format: "2015-08-07" "2015-11-29" "2015-08-11" ...

Comment: Ok, I see. `orderdate` already has the correct class and must not be converted twice. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with...

```
df$OrderDate <- as.Date(df$OrderDate, format="%d-%b-%y") #your dates are type character
df$prevOrders <- sapply(1:nrow(df),function(i)
                   sum(df$OrderDate<df$OrderDate[i] & df$id==df$id[i]))

df
    OrderDate id prevOrders
1  2017-07-01  1          0
2  2017-07-02  1          1
3  2017-07-02  2          0
4  2017-07-03  3          0
5  2017-07-01  4          0
6  2017-07-03  4          1
7  2017-07-05  5          0
8  2017-07-07  6          0
9  2017-07-09  2          1
10 2017-07-11  1          2
11 2017-07-13  4          2
12 2017-07-15  3          1
```